# Adding a link to Meta when the Stack Exchange network is under maintenance

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, maintenance

The following banner has been being shown at present when Stack Network is under maintenance.

> The site is currently in read-only mode; we'll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or visit [our status blog](https://stackstatus.net) for more info.

Now it has been observed that @StackStatus doesn't tweet the status update more frequently. For example, today the network was under maintenance but the most recent tweet was showing update till only 2nd of September, though later on it has been updated when maintenance was completed.

And I think "our status blog" a.k.a. [stackstatus.net](https://stackstatus.net) does nothing more than redirect visitors to a particular meta post.

So, I suggest to include a link to the meta post describing the planned maintenance so that visitors reading the banner can get information what exactly is going and when it is expected to be normal.

Following is an example of a possible improvement:

Generic Link:

> The site is currently in read-only mode; we'll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or visit [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance%2bor%2bsite-maintenance?tab=Newest) for more info

Specific Link:

> The site is currently in read-only mode due to the [planned maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370331/260388); we'll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or visit [our status blog](https://stackstatus.net) for more info.

Note: This may not be applicable to unplanned maintenance.

Comment: Duplicate of Feedback on the Announcement: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370386/282094

Comment: @Rob That was bug-reporting and this is feature-request I think.

Comment: Pandya, regulars to MSE are aware that [Feedback is placed on the Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bannouncements%5D+feedback+is%3Aanswer) and that this request [isn't new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsite-maintenance%5D+banner). There's nothing wrong with brining more attention to this important oversight, but that doesn't affect its duplicity if you bring nothing new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just published a package of fixes for read-only related bugs that included this one. We went ahead and took one of your suggestions, we've decided to display the list of most recent meta posts with the maintenance or site-maintenance tags in addition to the existing data there.

Thanks for such thoughtful reporting! We appreciate the help.